# Sharepoint 2010 Devices

Tags: sharepoint

How to get type of mobile devices that accessing sharepoint application? 
is there a custom code to detect that we are using blackberry,android or iphone to access sharepoint site.

Answer (score 0):

SharePoint can't tell you what device is accessing your site but it can provide the user agent. If you need the user agent during run time you should be able to use the System.Web.HttpRequest.UserAgent property. If you need the user agent for javascript reasons you can use navigator.userAgent.